# Wix installer - Error 1925 in Silent or Passive mode, but works fine in interactvie

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, uac

I have an MSI installer built with Wix. It does not require elevated privileges, having ALLUSERS=2 and MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1. It works fine in the user unteractive mode, but fails when launched from a non-elevated command prompt in the silent (/qn) or passive (/passive) mode.

The error in the log appearing straight after "Action start: InstallFinalize":

```
Error 1925. You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine.  Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.
```

Interestingly, if I run the installer from an admin command prompt in the silent mode, it succeeds. It installs into the per-user folder and writes registry to HKCU as expected, but when I uninstall it, it triggers the UAC elevation prompt, which suggests that there's some component there that has been installed per-machine, rather than per-user. Again, this does not happen if it was installed in the user-interactive mode.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? On the Package element have you set the InstallPrivileges and InstallScope, to what? Which version of Windows Installer is used?

Comment: We would need full logs and / or sources to really say anything at all. However, what is your setting for `InstallScope` in the `Package element`? Are all your folders per-user? In the compiled MSI, what is the word count value? I don't have Orca available right now, but it should be in the Summary Information Stream. Are `ALLUSERS` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` defined in the property table? (just checking). What WiX GUI dialog set do you use?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I don't set `InstallScope` on the Package element to anything because it sets `ALLUSERS` to either nothing or 1, but I need it to be 2 for the dual-purpose MSI. So I set `ALLUSERS` to 2 via a Property element. 

The `InstallPrivileges` attribute isn't set to anything either, so it defaults to 'elevated'. Otherwise, the user cannot choose to install per-machine. 

I use the WixUI_Advanced dialog set.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was with the `ALLUSERS` property. I had a custom action that set its value either to 1 or nothing before `FindRelatedProducts` to match the scope of any previously installed version so that it can be properly upgraded. Then, there was another custom action that reset the value of `ALLUSERS` back to 2 and set `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` appropriately instead. The problem was with that second custom action - apparently you shouldn't reset the value of `ALLUSERS` to 2 in the `InstallExecuteSequence`, but it's fine to do so in `InstallUISequence`.

Comment: This sounds hairy and risky. I assume you really need per-user installations - if you can get away without them you would be very wise to eliminate them. This isn't necessarily the prevailing prejudice for everyone, but I view per-user MSI setups as an anti-pattern for several reasons (technically dubious in several ways - it just doesn't make sense what happens during installation with all the folder redirects, hard to manage, upgrade, patch and uninstall).